# Помогите написать парсер на php

Tags: php

Смысл такой. Есть несколько сайтов. Нужно спарсить у одного url и title, у другого тоже.
Но если у одного сайта и другого заголовки title совпадают, то они пишутся вместе.
То есть: допустим, есть 2 колонки (url и title), если title одного сайта и другого совпадают, то появляется третья колонка с urlом другого сайта.

Через sitemap.xml делать не вариант. Пробовал - и ничего не выходит. Даже не знаю, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Не понятно ничего. title обрамляется на html тегом `<title></title>` в заголовочной части. url? На сайте нужно найти какой-то урл или урл самой страницы, так это парсить не нужно, он должен быть известен зарание, т. е. по урлу получаем HTML-код.

Comment: @dimkachel, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Копайте в сторону регулярных выражений и cURL.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Не совсем понятно поставлен вопрос, но, судя по всему, вы еще плохо знаете всю эту кухню про парсер сайтов. Читайте ссылки:
[Ссылка 1](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/72702/), [Ссылка 2](http://tekhnobuild.info/prostejshij-parser-na-php-s-curl).

В будущем пользуйтесь поисковиком, прежде чем задавать вопросы... Решение таких вопросов лежит как раз в изучении технологии. Волшебного ответа не найдете на форуме на такой абстрактный вопрос.